# Checkbox value undefined on online, works on localhost

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, localhost, lamp

Both local and online servers are LAMP (local MAMP, online CentOS with cPanel).
Everything runs fine on localhost, checkbox value is returned. But on online the checkbox value is always undefined

HTML + PHP:

```
<input class="force_status dont-keep-resending" type="checkbox" id="answer_to_q76" name="answer_to_q76" value="<?php echo ($q[76]->answer!='ok'?'remove':'ok'); ?>" rel="autosave" data-answer-id="<?php echo $q[76]->id; ?>" <?php if ($q[76]->answer==='ok') echo 'checked=checked'; ?>>
```

jQuery returns the object fine both on local and online (val.id is valid):

```
console.log($('[data-answer-id='+val.id+'][type=checkbox][rel=autosave].force_status'));
```

But on online the value of the checkbox is neither "ok" nor "remove" (the right values) but undefined. Setting the value with jQuery:

```
if (val.answer == 'ok')
                                        {
                                            console.log('making it ok');
                                            $('[data-answer-id='+val.id+'][type=checkbox][rel=autosave].force_status').val('ok');
                                            $('[data-answer-id='+val.id+'][type=checkbox][rel=autosave].force_status').prop('checked', 'true');
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            console.log('making it remove');
                                            $('[data-answer-id='+val.id+'][type=checkbox][rel=autosave].force_status').val('remove');
                                            $('[data-answer-id='+val.id+'][type=checkbox][rel=autosave].force_status').removeAttr('checked');
                                        }
```

- still leaves the online value undefined, when checked again jQuery still returns undefined on that checkbox

Any ideas why? Can't figure out why is works on localhost and not on online, the files are the same git diff and everything.

Comment: Use `.prop("checked", true);` without the commas on true (and then `.prop("checked", false);`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still undefined...

Comment: "Online" means you're using a different server which probably has a different version of PHP with a different configuration.